# put all of the string result in foreach loop to one variable

Tags: php, foreach

here is my code :

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.exampel.com');

foreach($html->find('item') as $article) {

    $item['title'] = $article->find('title', 0)->innertext;
    $item['description'] = $article->find('description', 0)->innertext;
    $item['description2'] .= $item['title'] .' : '. $item['description'] .'<br>'; 
    $articles[] = $item;

}

echo $item['description2'];
```

i use `$item['description2'] .=` to combine foreach result of `$item['description']`

echo worked but i got `"Notice: Undefined index: description2"`

What is the problem?

and how to put each of the loop result of `$item['description']` to one variable.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$item['description2']` the first time php try to concat the string.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.exampel.com');

foreach($html->find('item') as $article) {

    $item['title'] = $article->find('title', 0)->innertext;
    $item['description'] = $article->find('description', 0)->innertext;
    if (!isset($item['description2'])) {
        $item['description2'] = '';
    }
    $item['description2'] .= $item['title'] .' : '. $item['description'] .'<br>';
    $articles[] = $item;

}

echo $item['description2'];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy;